# In R, how do I keep the first single occurrence of a row based on a repeated value in one column?

Tags: r

I want to keep the row with the first occurrence of a changed value in a column (the last column in the example below). My dataframe is an xts object.

In the example below, I would keep the first row with a 2 in the last column, but not the next two because they are unchanged from the first 2. I'd then keep the next three rows (the sequence 323) because they change each time, and remove the next 4 because they didn't change, and so on. The final data frame would look like to smaller one below the original.

Any help is appreciated!

Original Dataframe

```
2007-01-31 2.72   4.75        2
2007-02-28 2.82   4.75        2
2007-03-31 2.85   4.75        2
2007-04-30 2.74   4.75        3
2007-05-31 2.46   4.75        2
2007-06-30 2.98   4.75        3
2007-07-31 4.19   4.75        3
2007-08-31 4.55   4.75        3
2007-09-30 4.20   4.75        3
2007-10-31 4.36   4.75        3
2007-11-30 5.75   4.76        4
2007-12-31 5.92   4.76        4
2008-01-31 6.95   4.87        4
2008-02-29 7.67   4.87        4
2008-03-31 8.21   4.90        4
2008-04-30 6.86   4.91        1
2008-05-31 6.53   5.07        1
2008-06-30 7.35   5.08        1
2008-07-31 8.00   5.13        4
2008-08-31 8.36   5.19        4
```

Final Dataframe

```
2007-01-31 2.72   4.75        2
2007-04-30 2.74   4.75        3
2007-05-31 2.46   4.75        2
2007-06-30 2.98   4.75        3
2007-11-30 5.75   4.76        4
2008-04-30 6.86   4.91        1
2008-07-31 8.00   5.13        4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `data.table::shift` to filter, plus the first row, in `rbind`

```
library(data.table)
rbind(setDT(dt)[1],dt[v3!=shift(v3)])
```

Or an equivalent approach using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(dt[1,], filter(dt, v3!=lag(v3)))
```

Output:

```
         date    v1    v2    v3
       <IDat> <num> <num> <int>
1: 2007-01-31  2.72  4.75     2
2: 2007-04-30  2.74  4.75     3
3: 2007-05-31  2.46  4.75     2
4: 2007-06-30  2.98  4.75     3
5: 2007-11-30  5.75  4.76     4
6: 2008-04-30  6.86  4.91     1
7: 2008-07-31  8.00  5.13     4
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have a solution using rle() as posted above but I am interested in your suggestion. The problem I have is that I am starting with an XTS object where the dates are the row names. They are not column 1. So when I convert the XTS object using data.table, I lose the date information. The algorithm works - I just don't have the date information for the rows.

Comment: instead of `setDT`, you can use `data.table(my_xts_object,keep.rownames = T)`; the `keep.rownames=T` will retain the dates as a column.

Comment: I tried the dplyr version and it worked like a charm. Thank you for your help - much appreciated!
Also, a very elegant solution :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's another solution using run length encoding [`rle()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/rle).

```
lens <- rle(df$V4)$lengths
df[cumsum(lens) - lens + 1,]
```

Output:

```
           V1   V2   V3 V4
1  2007-01-31 2.72 4.75  2
4  2007-04-30 2.74 4.75  3
5  2007-05-31 2.46 4.75  2
6  2007-06-30 2.98 4.75  3
11 2007-11-30 5.75 4.76  4
16 2008-04-30 6.86 4.91  1
19 2008-07-31 8.00 5.13  4
```

Comment: This worked very well when I passed the XTS object as a dataframe. Thank you for your speedy and elegant solution!

Answer (score 1):

**DATA**

```r
x <- "
2007-01-31 2.72   4.75        2
2007-02-28 2.82   4.75        2
2007-03-31 2.85   4.75        2
2007-04-30 2.74   4.75        3
2007-05-31 2.46   4.75        2
2007-06-30 2.98   4.75        3
2007-07-31 4.19   4.75        3
2007-08-31 4.55   4.75        3
2007-09-30 4.20   4.75        3
2007-10-31 4.36   4.75        3
2007-11-30 5.75   4.76        4
2007-12-31 5.92   4.76        4
2008-01-31 6.95   4.87        4
2008-02-29 7.67   4.87        4
2008-03-31 8.21   4.90        4
2008-04-30 6.86   4.91        1
2008-05-31 6.53   5.07        1
2008-06-30 7.35   5.08        1
2008-07-31 8.00   5.13        4
2008-08-31 8.36   5.19        4
"
df <- read.table(textConnection(x) , header = F)
```

and use this two lines

```
df$V5 <- c(1 ,diff(df$V4))
df[abs(df$V5) > 0 ,][1:4]

#>            V1   V2   V3 V4
#> 1  2007-01-31 2.72 4.75  2
#> 4  2007-04-30 2.74 4.75  3
#> 5  2007-05-31 2.46 4.75  2
#> 6  2007-06-30 2.98 4.75  3
#> 11 2007-11-30 5.75 4.76  4
#> 16 2008-04-30 6.86 4.91  1
#> 19 2008-07-31 8.00 5.13  4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>